# Ansible nested loops

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
device:
  - sdb: 2
  - sdc: 3
  - sdd: 4
```

How can I produce the result with ansible loops:

```
sdb 1
sdb 2
sdc 1
sdc 2
sdc 3
sdd 1
sdd 2
sdd 3
sdd 4
```

I tried `with_sequence` and `loop_control` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a debug task with ansible loop and jinja which should give you the desired result. Refactor as required.

```
- name: Debug device var
  debug:
    msg: "{% for key, value in item.iteritems() %}{% for i in range(value) %} {{ key }} {{ loop.index }} {% endfor %}{% endfor %}"
  loop: "{{ device }}"
```

Comment: Actually, I need use the result in the command. So how could I get the result without jinjia?

Comment: The output should be "sdc 1" "sdc 2" "sdc 3" instead of " sdc 1  sdc 2  sdc 3 " in each command line.

Comment: If you just need quotes around the values then use this (quotes need to be escaped for debug msg):

"{% for key, value in item.iteritems() %}{% for i in range(value) %}\"{{ key }} {{ loop.index }}\" {% endfor %}{% endfor %}"

Comment: I mean I need separated lines in each command, not just need the quotes. Maybe jinja isn't suitable for the case.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution but I changed the format of the variable, however. The variable is changed to:

```
device:
  sdb: 2
  sdc: 3
  sdd: 4
```

The result is:

```
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": "sdd 1"
}
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": "sdd 2"
}
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=3) => {
    "msg": "sdd 3"
}
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=4) => {
    "msg": "sdd 4"
}

TASK [osd : debug] 
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": "sdb 1"
}
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": "sdb 2"
}

TASK [osd : debug] 
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": "sdc 1"
}
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": "sdc 2"
}
ok: [ceph-host-2] => (item=3) => {
    "msg": "sdc 3"
}
```

main.yml

```
- include_tasks: inner.yml
  loop: "{{ device.keys() }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
```

inner.yml

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ outer_item }} {{ item }}"
  with_sequence: count={{ device[outer_item] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is:

```
device:
  - sdb: 2
  - sdc: 3
  - sdd: 4
```

main.yml

```
- include_tasks: inner.yml
  loop: "{{ device }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
```

inner.yml

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ outer_item.keys()[0] }}  {{ item }}"
  with_sequence: count={{ outer_item.values()[0] }}
```